# Cannot deploy using AWS code deploy : too few healthy instances are available for deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy an application to an ec2 instace from s3 bucket . I created an instance with the required s3 permimssion and also a code deploy application with required ec2 permissions

When I try to deploy thought I get :

```
The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS.
```

I shh into the ec2 instance to check the code deploy log and this is what I get in the :

```
2018-08-18 20:52:11 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2704)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
2018-08-18 20:52:11 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(2704)]: booting child: error during start or run: Errno::ENETUNREACH - Network is unreachable - connect(2) - /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize'
```

I tried changing the permissions , restarting the code deploy agent , creating a brand new codeDEploy application. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the agent to pick up commands from CodeDeploy, your host needs to have network access to the internet, which can be restricted by your EC2 security groups, VPC, configuration on your host, etc. To see if you have access, try pinging the CodeDeploy endpoint:

```
ping codedeploy.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Though you should use the endpoint for the region your host is in - see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#codedeploy_region).

If you've configured the agent to use the proxy config, you may have to restart the agent like [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/88).